# Деплой Node.js приложения на Windows Server через firedaemon

Tags: node.js, windows-server

Хотелось узнать, как можно задеплоить свое веб приложение на windows сервере через firedaemon. Десятки попыток не привели к нужному результату. Быть может я указываю не те параметры. Да, я знаю, что лучше поставить на какой-нибудь vps и не парится, но есть только винда. Параметры: [image: parameters])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто документация самого FireDaemon была не верна. Вот верные параметры. И все заработало. [image: Правильные параметры]